# FabricJS - What is Building?

Tags: fabricjs

I have installed NodeJS, added Express on top and now I cant make FabricJS work.

Do I have to follow the steps in https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/ under "Building" for FabricJS to work?

I tried running `$ node build.js` in the root of my app which gives me:

```
$ node build.js
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Drive\Personal\Sandbox\express-angular-app\build.j
s'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
```

And also in the fabric module folder which gives me:

```
$ node build.js
D:\Drive\Personal\Sandbox\express-angular-app\node_modules\fabric\build.js:93
      if (err) throw err;
               ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Drive\Personal\Sandbox\expres
s-angular-app\node_modules\fabric\HEADER.js'
    at Error (native)
```

I use Jade and I have the following in my `index.jade` and `fabric.js`:

[index.jade and fabric.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI8MV.png)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I confused back-end vs front-end. I was expecting the code to work from the backend by installing the fabric module via npm.

Instead I just added the CDN link in the head and it run in the client.

Comment: yes fabricjs is mainly a frontend lib. You can make it work on nodejs but just for some server side rendering, not for user interaction